# How to echo JS right after enqueued script to put it into noConflict mode?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I want to include and use third party JavaScript file ([Bootstrap Tooltip](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/tooltip.js)) in my plugin. Since Bootstrap is highly popular framework and `tooltip()` is rather generic name I want to make use of included `noConflict()` functionality to isolate tooltip's instance in my own variable.

If I understand timing at all right, this needs to be done right after script file loaded - so that nothing else has a chance to mess up instance (it had just set up) or get messed up by it either.

However there seems to be no convention in queue functionality to echo JS at such point. `$wp_scripts->print_extra_script()` is called *before* the script.

Is this at all possible to accomplish with current queue implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## WordPress >= 4.1

WordPress 4.1 had added [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) filter for complete HTML of enqueued script. Perfect for the purpose of adding something *right* after it.

---

### WordPress < 4.1

I ended up hooking into `wp_print_footer_scripts` at priority `11` (after queue has finished) and calling [`wp_print_scripts()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_print_scripts/) explicitly on script's handle, then echoing what I needed to.

I would be hesitant to use this for something major, but for small contained script it seems acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

You have to filter `script_loader_src`, check if you are on the correct script and add a one-time filter for `clean_url`. Then add your extra script, and make sure the output is syntactically valid.

Pretty simple, albeit rather hacky.

```
class Extra_Script
{
    private $extra = [];
    private $handle;
    private $url;
    private $versioned_url;

    public function __construct( $handle, $url )
    {
        $this->handle = $handle;
        $this->url    = $url;
        add_filter( 'script_loader_src', array( $this, 'filter_script_src' ), 10, 2 );
    }

    public function add_script( $script )
    {
        $this->extra[] = $script;
    }

    public function filter_script_src( $src, $handle )
    {
        if ( empty ( $this->extra ) )
            return $src;

        if ( $this->handle !== $handle )
            return $src;

        if ( 0 !== strpos( $src, $this->url ) )
            return $src;

        $this->versioned_url = $src;

        add_filter( 'clean_url', array( $this, 'filter_esc_url' ) );
        remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );

        return $src;
    }

    public function filter_esc_url( $url )
    {
        if ( $url !== $this->versioned_url )
            return $url;

        remove_filter( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );

        $scripts = join( "\n", $this->extra );

        return "$url'></script><script>$scripts</script><script class='";
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function()
{
    $handle = 'foo';
    $url    = plugins_url( '/foo.js', __FILE__ );

    wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $url );

    $extra = new Extra_Script( $handle, $url );
    $extra->add_script( "alert('bar!');" );
});
```

This will add an inline script right after your enqueued script.

An alternative might be [Patchwork](http://antecedent.github.io/patchwork/). You can redefine WordPress’ code at runtime with that. But that wouldn’t be less hacky.

Comment: Points for perversion, but I wouldn't ship this in public plugin. :) Had bad experience with WP changing escaping and messing things up in the past, staying away from those parts.

Answer (score 2):

Today I needed to do more or less same thing, ending up on an alternative solution, that I want to share in case it can be useful for someone.

I wrote a custom class extending `WP_Script`, something like this:

```
class GM_Scripts extends WP_Scripts {

    static function buildFromWp( WP_Scripts $scripts ) {
        $class = get_called_class();
        $obj = new $class;
        foreach ( get_object_vars( $scripts ) as $n => $v ) {
            $obj->$n = $v;
        }
        return $obj;
    }

    public function do_item( $handle, $group = false ) {
        $done = parent::do_item( $handle, $group );
        do_action( 'after_script_done', $handle, $done );
    }

}
```

This class inherit all methods from parent WP class, except one, `do_item` that is the one used to effectively print script on markup.

`GM_Scripts::do_item()` calls same method on `WP_Script` and immediately after fires the custom action `'after_script_done'` passing as arguments the script handle and a boolean that is true if the script was effectively print on page.

After that, I hooked `wp_print_scripts` to overwrite the global `$wp_scripts` object with an instance of my class, built using the static method `buildFromWp` that inherits the status of a `WP_Scripts` passed as argument.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', function() {

  if ( is_admin() || did_action('login_head') || ! isset($GLOBALS['wp_scripts']) ) {
    return;
  }

  $GLOBALS[ 'wp_scripts' ] = GM_Scripts::buildFromWp( $GLOBALS[ 'wp_scripts' ] );

}, 0 );
```

Once my instance inherits status, type and and methods of original WP class that should not cause any issue with WordPress or third parties code.

Also, this happen only on fronted, to further reduce any chance of conflicts.

Finally I added the action that echo what I need:

```
add_action( 'after_script_done', function( $handle, $done ) {

  if ( $handle === 'myscript' && $done ) {
     // echo what needed
  }

}, 0, 2 );
```

and enqueued my script as usual:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', function() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', $script_url );

} );
```

What's the benefit of this approach against the accepted one?

First of all it is a more generic approach usable for every script, and more important, any dependency to my script is solved correctly.

As example, another piece of code can use

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', function() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'another-script', $another_url, array( 'myscript' ) );

} );
```

Using the accepted approach, in this case

- if my script is already registered before `'wp_head'` it will be inserted in page without no conflict or whatever I want to print after it
- if it isn't registereded the `'another-script'` will not be inserted because WordPress will not be able to solve the dependency